# Using preferences in Quickly

Tags: quickly

There are a lot of questions about some small aspects of it, but, to be honest, there is no explanation at all on the internet of using preferences in quickly. How to bind widgets' content with u1db (?) entries and refresh them? I just couldn't find anything about it, except for answers to some specific problems.

Comment: It's a good question, but I don't use quickly any more since it came out a little pre-maturely and left a bad taste in my fingers.  I tried to like it, and it seemed like a good idea.  It screamed too soon though.  I liked what they were trying to do, so I really tried to use it, but for me it didn't pan out.  If you're trying to do something relatively simple, it's easier to just learn debian packaging.

Comment: Using quickly is definitely easier, then learning debian packaging! And it is not only that: quickly helps very much by creating a template of the app, so you don't have to do anything like using builder etc. by hand. It is of great help for programming by non-programmers like myself.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an abandoned by its developers.